# Refinerycms did not generate image field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, refinerycms

I was following [RefineryCMS getting started tutorial about generatin an extension](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#generating-an-extension). 
I put following command in my project directory:

```
rails generate refinery:engine event title:string date:datetime photo:image blurb:text
```

And it generated it almost properly. The problem is that it handled photo as a regular *input* string. According to the guide it should be *image picker field*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you: [Why is there no image after creating a record in Refinery CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521309/where-is-there-no-image-after-creating-record-in-refinery-cms)

I've found it while searching for the solution to the same problem, but have not tried it.

Comment: This seems more like a suggestion rather than an answer. For suggestions or clarifications please add a comment to the question.